# how to use multiple criteria in AVERAGEIF function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I want to calculate the average buy price of stocks:

[image]

for the average column I have the following formula: `=AVERAGEIF(C:C,C2,H:H)`

But that calculates it for all. I'm trying to add a second criteria, I tried

`=AVERAGEIF(C:C,C2 AND G2="Buy",H:H)`

but it returns an error. How do I chain criterias?

Comment: Check [AverageIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/averageifs-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AVERAGEIFS formula for multiple conditions. Just keep in mind that parameter orders are slightly different from AVERAGEIF.

Your usage may be,

```
=AVERAGEIFS(H:H, C:C, C2, G:G, "Buy")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `AVERAGE` array function with `IF` included:

```
{=AVERAGE(IF((C2=C:C)*("Buy"=G:G);H:H))}
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]